# How to Have Multiple or Conditions for While Loop

Tags: matlab, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a basic while loop to get back into the swing of things with matlab. All I'm trying to do is create a prompt to ask the user if today is their birthday and if they say yes it'll wish them happy birthday and if they say no it'll say "that's too bad". I can make the prompts appear but what I want to do is unless the user inputs 'yes' or 'no' they will continually be asked if today is their birthday. My question is how I create the loop to prompt my question over and over until the user inputs 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: So you want to [compare strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/string-comparison.html) to one thing [`or`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) another and stay in a [`while` loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) until the comparison is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while 1
    b = input('Is today your birthday? ','s');
    if any(strcmpi(b,{'yes','no'}))
       break
    end
end
```

Comment: The correct way to indicate that an answer is perfect is to accept it, not to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way (there are many others):

Use a while loop in which you put the prompt (here I use [inputdlg](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html)) and once the user enters the answer, you check if the string entered compares to either yes, Yes, no and No. If it does not, the dialog box pops up again. If it fits, a message appears.

In order to compare multiple strings at once, you can use `strcmp` with the answer provided by the user and use a cell array containing the strings you are looking for (i.e. yes/no/etc.). If the answer corresponds to any of the strings, the array (called `CheckAns`) contains a 1 and the sum is different than 0; otherwise the sum equals 0 so the loop continues.
That's a lot of words so here is the code:

```
%// Initialize the look up array. All 0 to start and enter the loop
CheckAns = [0 0 0 0];

while ~sum(CheckAns)

    Ans = inputdlg('Is this your birthday?');

    CheckAns = strcmpi(Ans,{'yes';'no'});

    if strcmpi(Ans,'yes')
        disp('Happy birthday')

    elseif strcmpi(Ans,'no')

        disp('Haha loser')

    end

end
```